# UITableView scrolling lag with multiple Custom UiTableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a chat application that supports simple text messages, audio messages, and 2 other types of messages, all 4 of them have different UI so to create them I have used 4 different Custom Cells with Nib files each, The problem is UITableView scrolling lags after some cells have been added to the tableview.

All the messages are displayed in bubbles of sizes according to either their text or audio file duration, for this I use `[UIImage:resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode];` for the bubble size. I think this is the issue.. but would be glad if any one identifies anything else in this..

Thank you.

Comment: You can save image in memory instead of using [UIImage:resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode]; everytime

Comment: Save in memory as in? NSCache..?

Comment: or may be in some imageview as iVar of view controller

Comment: its a list of images chat bubbles not a single imageview that i could store as iVar..

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past with varying cell heights.  Does it still lag if the cell heights are all the same?

Comment: 4 custom cells.. 3 of them are fixed, one of them(the text msgs one) has height calculated on the fly.

Comment: You should use Instrument's Time Profiler to find what the cause of the slowdown is. Its possible that its the cell height calculation or even some CALayer manipualtions slow down scroll views badly. Very hard to diagnose when there's very little detail.